# Google maps full height style angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, google-maps

I am struggling to get a full-height Google map displayed on my site.

```
<section data-ng-controller="LocationsController" data-ng-init="find()">
<map center="41.454161, 13.18461" zoom="6">
    <span data-ng-repeat="location in locations">
        <marker position="{{location.latitude}},{{location.longitude}}"
         title="{{location.name}}"></marker>
    </span>
</map>
</section>
```

I am forced now to pass a style-attribute for height on the  element, otherwise the [framework ngMaps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) will [output a default height of 300px to the element as an inline style](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js#L1436).

Things I already tried were to overwrite style-attribute with jQuery .css() as well as defining the outer divs to 100% in width and height, but neither worked or the style set by ngMaps was not overwritten or the map disappeared completely.

If I want to achieve to display the map on 100% height, what else can I do that will make it work?

Comment: What does your CSS for the element look like? I remember that the angular maps requires a height to function.

Comment: The map element has: 
  display: block;
  height: 300px;

Comment: by full height, do you mean you want to show full screen map?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `default-style="false"` into your map directive like this to remove the 300px inline style:

```
<map center="41.454161, 13.18461" zoom="6" default-style="false">
```

Then in your CSS, define the desired size like the answer above but specifying the correct selector:

```
map {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if adding "position:absolute" to the CSS helps -

```
.map  {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```